# Dell laptop graphics

Tags: windows-7, laptop, graphics-card

i just installed new win7 32bit on my laptop dell inspiron 5110 
and i am facing some problems in video driver
i can not increase lighting up and down using `fn+f4 , fn+f5` keys

another problem can not increase my resolution
it appears to me only `800X600` and `1024X768`

another problem in `Appearance and Personalization` there is `problems with transparency and other Aero effects`

Comment: "problems with transparency and other Aero effects" What problems? Please be explicit. Have you updated your video drivers? Have you installed the Dell utilities for your laptop?

Comment: why don't you install a 64Bit Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Go to support.dell.com and either put in your service tag # or let it detect your system.  I'd try and install whatever drivers it detects you need or try the system drivers and the video drivers.  Click on start->right click on computer and go to properties, go to device manager and look for any issues there as well.  May also want to run Microsoft update to search for drivers.

Comment: i used auto driver update using support.dell.com , and it tells me that i have 3driver updates ready to download and install.
Video |ATI Mobility Radeon HD 7570M Driver (455MB)
Mouse, Keyboard & Input Devices |Dell Touchpad Driver (10MB)
Audio |IDT 92HD87B1, v.6.10.0.6324, A02 (28MB)

i downloaded the first one and trying to install it but no way
it only unzipped and don't install 
any help please

Comment: You need to find them (probably in C:\Dell\Drivers\whatever driver) and then run the setup file.  Strange, they normally start the installation process themselves.